# Does WATCH_DOGS feature a "quest generation"?

Tags: watch-dogs

I've somehow read that I cannot fight against Gang Hideouts after I cleared all of them. Is this also true for other quests?

So when I do everything I'm completely done with the game and I cannot play these Jobs again?

Or does Watch underscore Dogs festure some sort of random quest generation? 
(For example pick 2 random locations and 1-10 random vehicle, let them drive from A to B and call it a "criminal convoy")

I hope someone can answer this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options screen there should be an option to reset gang hideouts. I think this was added post-release.
As for the other missions, I cannot say. Although I assume they are not random based on how they behave compared to say, crimes.